# Optimize the number of ng-repeat |angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I want to separate everything in my code according to predefined  levels given , from level 1 to level 6 , now my JSON reads

```
$scope.myJson=[{
  id: 1,
  level: 1,
  name: "any name"
},
{
  id: 2,
  level: 2,
  name: "any name"
},
{
  id: 3,
  level: 2,
  name: "any name"
}....]
```

now in my HTML I have written something like

```
<div>level 1
  <div ng-repeat="prod in myJson"  ng-if="prod.level==1">{{prod.name}}
  </div>
</div>
<div>level 2
  <div ng-repeat="prod in myJson"  ng-if="prod.level==2">{{prod.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

and so on , I want to use only one ng-repeat to filter all the results in HTML on basis of the levels , as the results number in thousands the app is taking too much of time to respond

Answer (score 1):

You could try a switch case in your ng repeat, for example :

```
<div ng-repeat="prod in myJson">
   <div ng-switch-on = "prod.level">
        <div ng-switch-when="1">
             Level 1 {{prod.name}}
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="2">
             Level 2 {{prod.name}}
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-default>
             Another level {{prod.name}}
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So you will only do one run over your data.

Comment: I have heard that the ng-switch would internally do the same number of comparisons, if that is so would that not make the app same level of slow?

Comment: I need to print prod.name in the place

Comment: I doesn't know the angular core enough to tel you exactly why :/ but maybe you could try filtering your JSON if you get it from a REST API.

Comment: that is what the problem is they havent created an api to perform comparisons like this , so i have to do it on the UI level

Comment: the problem with this solution is that the level name is displayed number if times  , which is not desired and can be gained by simple orderby too

Answer (score 1):

To make it more generic, `groupBy` will solve this for you.

Demo:

```js
angular.module('app', ['angular.filter'])
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myJson = [{
      id: 1,
      level: 1,
      name: "any name level1"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      level: 2,
      name: "any name level2"
    }, {
      id: 3,
      level: 2,
      name: "any name level2"
    }, {
      id: 4,
      level: 2,
      name: "any name level2"
    }, {
      id: 5,
      level: 1,
      name: "any name level1"
    }, {
      id: 6,
      level: 3,
      name: "any name level3"
    }]
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.4.7/angular-filter.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in myJson | groupBy: 'level'">
      Level- {{ key }}
      <li ng-repeat="item in value">
        {{ item.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you have two objects with same level it doesn'work

Comment: exactly there are a lot of objects at same level

Comment: @Vibhor and @Nicolò Bosch : valid point, so updated my answer. `groupby` will suit your need.